# Can I send an SMS from a service?

Tags: android, sms

So i want to write a PoC app for an idea that I have. One of the feature that my app would do is send a text message (and perhaps receive delivery notification). Its not going to be an SMS app. Just a service which might run in the background and sends sms on some particular interval, unattended (of course with user consent).

i remember in some of android api release, Google took the decision that you can only send receive sms if you have selected your app to be "default" sms app ? I don't remember exactly.

So the question is, can my app (as a service) send an sms and receive delivery notification while not being an SMS app ?

Whenever I try to Google this question, I find *how to send sms* example with `SMSManager` and the code to send the sms but no where i could find this answer.

Answer (score 1):

> So the question is, can my app (as a service) send an sms and receive delivery notification while not being an SMS app ?

Yes. Since KitKat, there has been the concept of a default SMS app, which is what I believe you're referring to.

The main difference in the way SMS are handled as of that version is that only the default SMS app has write access to the Provider, but any other app can still send and receive messages as usual. If your app is not the default, any messages it sends will automatically be written to the Provider by the system.

Furthermore, the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast can no longer be aborted, so you don't have to worry about some other app intercepting incoming messages before your app gets a chance to handle them.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on **any messages it sends will automatically be written to the Provider by the system.** ? What do you mean by that ? Who is provider here ? Written to system ? means written to smsdb ?

Comment: Provider refers to the SMS `ContentProvider` which handles the transactions on the SMS table in the centralized MMS/SMS database, and with which the app interacts via a `ContentResolver`. It's how multiple SMS apps on a device can all show the same messages. Before KitKat, if your app sent a message using `SmsManager`, your app itself had to write it to the Provider if you wanted it to show up in, for example, the native SMS app. As of KitKat, since a non-default app doesn't have write access to the Provider, the system takes care of writing its outgoing messages for it.